# How to inform users of update or to rate app when they are connected to internet?

Tags: android, youtube

How can I make that when user is connected to internet it asks him to rate app or it tells him that there is update for app ?
And is it possible to make changes to your app without having users to update app? Just like for example youtube app changed it design without me having to update it ?

Comment: [How do i ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

**For your first question** - you can use broadcast receiver to get notification or to perform any task whenever user connects to the internet. You can register the receiver statically in manifest if you want to perform action even if user is not using application at that moment of time or else you can register your receiver dynamically.

**Your second question**- Youtube provides updates on regular basis and if it does not requires any special permission and depending upon setting of the phone it updates in the back ground. You can update graphics on launcher activity using any web service to download your new graphics but it is not the proper way. User should know about any changes and any downloads you do.